# Script task problem listing excel files in a directory

Tags: c#, excel, ssis, etl, script-task

**Problem:**

I have excel sheets in a folder on my D: drive. I want to see all the excel files in the variable in a Script task.

**SSIS variables:**

```
ReadOnly: Folderpath
Read and Write only: ExcelFiles
```

**C# Code:**

```
const string FILE_PATTERN = "*.xlsx";

string excelFolder;
string[] excelFiles;

excelFolder = Dts.Variables["ExcelFolder"].Value.ToString();
excelFiles = Directory.GetFiles(excelFolder, FILE_PATTERN);

Dts.Variables["ExcelFiles"].Value = excelFiles;
//MessageBox.Show(excelFiles.ToString());

Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

I am wondering why this code is not working. Also I saw that the string[] is not catching anything.

Any input will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You're looking for Excel files, right?  Isn't the FILE_PATTERN string for .sql files?

Comment: @userfl89 I am sorry it is excel extension(.xlsx)but it doesn't run even.Also I am trying it for different extensions but it is not working.

Comment: Why not do whatever you are attempting to do in a foreach loop in SSIS enumerating on files?

Answer (score 0):

## Trying to figure out the issue

I think your code is looking fine but it needs some improvement:

```
const string FILE_PATTERN = "*.xlsx";

string excelFolder;
string[] excelFiles;

excelFolder = Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString();
excelFiles = Directory.GetFiles(excelFolder, FILE_PATTERN,SearchOption.AllDirectories);

Dts.Variables["User::ExcelFiles"].Value = excelFiles;
//MessageBox.Show(excelFiles.ToString());

Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

1. First of all you was passing `ExcelFolder` as variable name when it should be `FolderPath` as you mentioned.
2. The second improvement is to select `SearchOption.AllDirectories` since it the excel files may be found in subdirectories not on the main directory.
3. Add the variable modifier `User::` if the variables are user variables

If these suggestion didn't work, then check that the `FolderPath` value is appropriate.

## Better approach

If you are looking to loop over excel files then you should use  a Foreach Loop container to achieve that instead of a Script Task. There is many articles that describe the whole process step-by-step:

- [How to read data from multiple Excel files with SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4165/how-to-read-data-from-multiple-excel-files-with-sql-server-integration-services/)
- [Loop Through Excel Files in SSIS](https://mikedavissql.com/2013/09/16/loop-through-excel-files-in-ssis/)
- [Loop through Excel Files and Tables by Using a Foreach Loop Container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/loop-through-excel-files-and-tables-by-using-a-foreach-loop-container?view=sql-server-2017)